# SQL Server vs MySQL/PHP and BIG O

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

A fellow colleague mentioned to me that SQL Server does not apply to Big O as it does with MySQL/PHP.

Anything that takes CPU time has a Big O...

Could I be misunderstanding something? I mean if queries are ran, there's always an Big O? how could SQL Server be except or be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big O notation is just a way to determine the running time of an algorithm in function of the size of the data it operates on. For example, quicksort has an average running time O(n log n). However, it can have a worst case of O(n^2) and optimised versions exist (in place) that run at O(log n). Every operation and query that the database server needs to perform (i.e., an algorithm) will have accordingly a running time which can be expressed with Big O notation.

For a database for example, the SELECT query is O(n) in general, and can be O(log n) with an index present. It doesn't matter if this is MySQL or Oracle or MS SQL.

I believe MS SQL has a tool called Estimated Execution Plan in SQL Server Management Studio which can help you find execution times.

In short, seems the details of your story are missing, or someone understood something wrong.

Comment: Nailed it.  It was exactly what I was mentioning as well.  I think we're just on two different pages here with understanding.  Anything that has overhead or some CPU time has a Big O...

Answer (score 0):

You should talk to your colleagues about what they mean.

"Big O" refers to the time-complexity of the algorithm with respect to size of the input.  ([See](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) here for a discussion of the topic.)  The "Big O" estimate itself is the upper bound of the time complexity.

Time complexity is a characteristic of an algorithm.  The code to run a SQL query implements the algorithm for that query.  Hence, the query would have some time complexity measure associated with it.  This would apply to all databases.